# How to get latest version of Plutus in project file of plutus-starter-devcontainer

Tags: plutus, git, nix-shell

I've been trying to get the latest version of `plutus` on my project but I get the following error message when I run `nix-shell`:

`error: attribute '8a20664f00d8f396920385947903761a9a897fe0' missing, at /nix/store/przi4l85b1yd1irwss0qnhg1lsw2925k-haskell.nix-src/modules/cabal-project.nix:118:37`

In the `cabal.project` file, I made the change of the tag from:

```
-- Plutus revision from 2021/06/11
source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus.git
  subdir:
    freer-extras
    playground-common
    plutus-core
    plutus-contract
    plutus-ledger
    plutus-ledger-api
    plutus-tx
    plutus-tx-plugin
    plutus-pab
    plutus-use-cases
    prettyprinter-configurable
    quickcheck-dynamic
    word-array
  tag: plutus-starter-devcontainer/v1.0.6
```

to the latest `plutus` tag, which is currently `8a20664f00d8f396920385947903761a9a897fe0`

The line (118) the error refers to in `cabal.project.nix` is as follows:

`then { location, tag, ...}: config.sha256map.${location}.${tag}`

OR

```
    lookupSha256 = mkOption {
      type = nullOr unspecified;
      default = if config.sha256map != null
        then { location, tag, ...}: config.sha256map.${location}.${tag} -- <- Error here
        else _: null;
    };
```

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction on how to fetch the latest version from the plutus repo?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by copying the content of `cabal.project` from one of the latest examples in the plutus pioneer program to the `cabal.project` file of my own project - while ensuring that the `index-state` is left out.

Copying the content of the file also requires that I update `nix/pkgs/haskell/haskell.nix` with the latest tags of the `source-repository-package`s in the `cabal.project` file and their corresponding `sha256` hashes (this is gotten from running `nix-shell --show-trace` repeatedly and observing the error messages for wrong expected `sha256` hash)

```
    sha256map = {
      ...
      "https://github.com/Quid2/flat.git"."95e5d7488451e43062ca84d5376b3adcc465f1cd" = "06l31x3y93rjpryvlxnpsyq2zyxvb0z6lik6yq2fvh36i5zwvwa3";
      "https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus.git"."2f11c28bd8f6d630daab582255e16d8408075bd7" = "0sh4mfsanvdg43qhq321v24vamrw7nzc6gpjb0d34nyrq2lw55wj";
      "https://github.com/shmish111/purescript-bridge.git"."6a92d7853ea514be8b70bab5e72077bf5a510596" = "13j64vv116in3c204qsl1v0ajphac9fqvsjp7x3zzfr7n7g61drb";
      ...
    }
```

Afterwards, I ran `cabal update` and replaced the new index state on the `cabal.project` file with the new index state generated by cabal and running `nix-shell` works, finally!

Comment: Hopefully someone finds or makes a better way...